# Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I want to run the facbar-samples on windows10,reference the http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html but get the error:

```
$ ./startFabric.sh
orderer.example.com is up-to-date
couchdb is up-to-date
peer0.org1.example.com is up-to-date
cli is up-to-date
2017-07-05 08:17:06.550 UTC [main] main -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because 
cannot init crypto, missing /etc/hyperledger/fabric/C:/Program 
Files/Git/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp folder
```

some that I have installed:

```
$ npm -v
5.0.4
$ node -v
v6.11.0
$ curl -V
curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.54.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2l zlib/1.2.11 
libssh2/1.8.0 nghttp2/1.23.1 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 
pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 
HTTPS-proxy Metalink

$ docker --version
Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87

$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.14.0, build c7bdf9e3

$ git --version
git version 2.13.1.windows.2
```

Please help ,Thanks.

Comment: I had faced similar problem before, and realized that it would be better if I use vagrant to quickly build up a VM to experiment. That way I wouldn't have to worry about windows specific issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a problem with mingw64 which is messing with the filepaths.
The solution is to set the following environment variable before running startFabric.sh :

export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1

A fix was just submitted to fabric to do that for you so if you pull the latest version from the master branch it should work. Otherwise, just set that variable and that should solve your problem.

Arnaud

Comment: I put it into the shell and It is more useful ,Thanks.

Comment: I have "export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1" added in the shell but I am still getting this error. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is incorrect path to certificates  (look for windows path string between /fabric and /etc) 
*/etc/hyperledger/fabric/C:/ProgramFiles/Git/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp*

You can try next :

- add path to certificate as environment variable to docker compose file at peer section
- start network using **docker-compose -f "path_to_file"**
- manually run instructions in startFabric.sh at peer and cli.
- then you can successfully run **node query.js**  for testing network work

Answer (score 1):

The double // in the path will fix this. Update in all the places where docker exec command used
for e.g. MSPCONFIGPATH=//etc/hyperledger....

Also certificates have to be generated before you could get your network running

Comment: The double // is useful  . But I don't generated certificates and is work normal。Maybe it has done。

Answer (score 1):

Do this `./byfn.sh -m down` first and then run `./byfn.sh generate` then `./byfn.sh -m up`

Answer (score 1):

This may happen possibly when the `network.sh` is set to `down`. So, try bringing it `up` with the `-ca` flags and check. Worked for me.

Comment: This also worked for me. Seems that it needs the certificate authorities for `init crypto`.

Answer (score 0):

Before you run the fabcar-samples, I think that you have to execute some steps from the "Building Your First Network" chapter. It seems that you haven't got the required *certificates* to start the network. Also, you should generate the *genesis block*, the *channel configuration transaction* and the *anchor peers*.

You can do it by executing the `./byfn.sh -m generate` command. For more information: http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#generate-network-artifacts

Comment: It isn't necessary to run anything from the "Building Your First Network" tutorial before running the fabcar sample.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same using Fabric 2.2's Test-Network. To resolve,

1. Start docker again
2. Set FABRIC_CFG_PATH, CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED, CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID, CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE, CORE_PEER_ADDRESS and CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH again
3. Run your queries from the test-network sub-directory.