# Error: Cannot find module 'fabric-client'

Tags: npm-install, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

After normal run the ./startFabric.sh(it shows as follow ):

```
2017-07-21 07:47:37.477 UTC [chaincodeCmd] chaincodeInvokeOrQuery -> INFO 
00a Chaincode invoke successful. result: status:200
2017-07-21 07:47:37.477 UTC [main] main -> INFO 00b Exiting.....
Total execution time : 364 secs ...
```

Then I try to run `npm install`in the `\facbar` But I  get err again .

```
$ npm install

> grpc@1.2.4 install C:\Users\Lenovo.WIN10-20170627G\Desktop\fabric-samples-
release\fabcar\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
node-pre-gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Lenovo.WIN10-20170627G\\Desktop\\fabric-
samples-release\\fabcar\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-
gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp',
node-pre-gyp verb cli   'install',
node-pre-gyp verb cli   '--fallback-to-build' ]
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.6.34
node-pre-gyp info using node@6.11.0 | win32 | x64
node-pre-gyp verb command install []
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Users\Lenovo.WIN10-
20170627G\Desktop\fabric-samples-
release\fabcar\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\grpc_node.node" 
(not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-
binaries/node/grpc/v1.2.4/node-v48-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 200 https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-
binaries/node/grpc/v1.2.4/node-v48-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp info install unpacking grpc_node.node
node-pre-gyp info tarball done parsing tarball
node-pre-gyp info validate Running test command: 'C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node.exe --eval 'require(\'C:/Users/Lenovo.WIN10-
20170627G/Desktop/fabric-samplesrelease/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/grpc_node.node\')''
[grpc] Success: "C:\Users\Lenovo.WIN10-20170627G\Desktop\fabric-samples-release\fabcar\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\grpc_node.node" is 
installed via remote
node-pre-gyp info ok

> x509@0.3.2 install C:\Users\Lenovo.WIN10-20170627G\Desktop\fabric-samples-release\fabcar\node_modules\x509
> node-gyp rebuild
C:\Users\Lenovo.WIN10-20170627G\Desktop\fabric-samples-release\fabcar\node_modules\x509>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node 
"C:\Users\Lenovo.WIN10-
20170627G\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-
bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" 
rebuild )
▒ڴ˽▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒һ▒▒▒▒▒▒һ▒▒▒▒Ŀ▒▒▒▒Ҫ▒▒▒ò▒▒▒▒▒▒ɣ▒▒▒▒▒ӡ▒/m▒▒▒▒▒ء▒
MSBUILD : error MSB4132: ▒޷▒ʶ▒߰汾▒▒2.0▒▒▒▒▒▒▒õĹ▒▒߰汾Ϊ "4.0"▒▒
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: 
`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit 
code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Lenovo.WIN10-
20170627G\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-
gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" 
"C:\\Users\\Lenovo.WIN10-
20170627G\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-
gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Lenovo.WIN10-20170627G\Desktop\fabric-samples-
release\fabcar\node_modules\x509
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN fabcar@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! x509@0.3.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the x509@0.3.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lenovo.WIN10-20170627G\AppData\Roaming\npm-
cache\_logs\2017-07-21T07_51_26_723Z-debug.log
```

Then I try to exe `node query.js` I found the node moudles `fabric-client`doesn't install.

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'fabric-client'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lenovo.WIN10-20170627G\Desktop\fabric-samples-release\fabcar\query.js:11:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

I try `node install fabric-client` and get the same err as `npm install` start from

```
> x509@0.3.2 install C:\Users\Lenovo.WIN10-20170627G\Desktop\fabric-samples-
release\fabcar\node_modules\x509
> node-gyp rebuild.
```

to the end .


The environment is same to  :
[Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921180/cannot-run-peer-because-cannot-init-crypto) 
Please help ,Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you don't have all the required pieces for npm to work on Windows.
Try to do a "npm install --global windows-build-tools" and once this is done, rerun "npm install".
For more info, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools

Arnaud

Comment: It is useful，Despite take me  4G space and 30 minutes。After that ,I run the `node query.js`,Cannot find module 'C:\Go\src\github.com\fabric-samples\fabcar\node_modul
es\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\grpc_node.node' ,Then I run the `npm install grpc` .Finally ,it works normal.Thanks very much.

Comment: Thanks for the report. I'll add that to the doc.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I did

> $ npm update

This should include fabric-client@1.1.2 (at DateTime.Now = Jun/09/2018)

Answer (score 1):

Fabric client and Fabric CA client packages are needed to run this, which you have to install by "npm install" in the folder, if this operation is unsuccessful, remove the node_modules folder and then reinstall it , you can use "rm -rf node_modules" to remove it.

Comment: Should we run the `npm install` cmd inside the javascript folder or the fabcar folder?

Comment: @LordDraagon inside the fabcar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on mac and I had to re-install the xcode tools

```
sudo rm -rf $(xcode-select -print-path)
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rm package-lock.json
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

That should fix issue and install all packages.