# Not able to execute fabcar demo in Hyperledger

Tags: node.js, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am tring to execute fabcar example from Hyperledger-fabric where I have created few cars. When I try to execute

```
node query.js
```

at ../fabric-samples/fabcar I am getting an error

```
fabric-client not found
```

If I execute

```
npm install
```

I have node 6.9.0 and npm 3.10.0
I am getting error like this

```
> grpc@1.2.4 install /home/.../fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.2.4/node-v57-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.2.4 and node@8.0.0 (node-v57 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/8.0.0"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/home/.../fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/.node-gyp"
make: Entering directory '/home/.../fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/build'
make: *** No rule to make target '../.node-gyp/8.0.0/include/node/common.gypi', needed by 'Makefile'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory '/home/.../fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:197:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-42-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/.../fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/home/.../fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src /node/extension_binary"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/.../fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v8.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/.../fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/grpc_node.node
--module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/home/.../fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/.../fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:887:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:208:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-42-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/.../fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/.../fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.0.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.34
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build  --module=/home/.../fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node  --module_path=/home/.../fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src /node/extension_binary' (1)
fabcar@1.0.0 /home/.../fabric-samples/fabcar`-- (empty)

npm WARN fabcar@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-42-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v8.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! grpc@1.2.4 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.2.4 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the grpc package
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs grpc
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls grpc
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/.../fabric-samples/fabcar/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

can anyone help me to execute the code

Comment: are you running windows? if so, please see this SO topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45232825/error-cannot-find-module-fabric-client. If not, may I ask what version of Python is installed?

Comment: Was your connection to the internet up at the time?  The first lines from the error pasted above look to indicate an issue trying to download.  You might want to try install node-gyp manually - npm install -g node-gyp and make sure you have the prereqs - https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was solved after deleting directory node_module and then  doing
    npm install