# Cannot run peer in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

**Problem:**

I have set up a blockchain application using Hyperledger fabric and I did lots of transactions using my client application which in React Through Node SDK backend. But today I tried to restart the network but it did not start any peer and gave me this error.

> Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, folder
>   "//opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp"
>   does not exist

I tried all the solution provided in this question.

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921180/cannot-run-peer-because-cannot-init-crypto)

Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide some details on your environment?  Host OS, Docker distro (e.g. Docker for Windows, Docker Toolbox), how are you running Fabric, etc

Comment: @GariSingh I am using Docker for Windows to run Fabric

Comment: How are you stopping and then starting the network?  And what is actually using `//opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp`  ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by resetting docker.